# Cache keeps data from previous record

Tags: react-admin

Let's assume that I have two posts :

```
 { id:1, title:'Post 1', content: 'Content1', additionalData:'additionalData 1'}
 { id:2, title:'Post 2', content: 'Content2'}
```

In my edit view pages I have a direct link to go to de next post so i can navigate like that :

*myapplication.com/posts/1*  --> Click on a link to go to --> *myapplication.com/posts/2*

**I am now on the edit view page of POST 2**

**Expected** : field title : Post 2, field content : Content 2, field additionalData: empty

**Actual** : field title : Post 2, field content : Content 2, field *additionalData: additionalData 1*

So the previous additonalData **is cached from the POST 1** and displayed in the edit view of POST 2...

Keep in mind that :

-> I don't have that issue if i go to POST 2 **from the list view**

-> This issue happens only if **i use a direct link** from POST 1 to POST 2

Disabling the cache fixed my issue.. But it's a quit radical way of fixing it..

Answer (score 0):

Tough to know without seeing more of the code.
You could try modifying the [Mutation Mode](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Edit.html#mutationmode) to `pessimistic`.